# Chrome Notifications moved to Windows 10 Action Center cannot be cleared?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, windows-10

So this is a weird one. If you create a chrome notification using chrome.notifications.create, you are only able to carry out other methods involving the specified notification id while the note is on screen. Once it slides off the screen, it cannot be enumerated with chrome.notifications.getAll() nor can it be cleared with chrome.notifications.clear(). Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The API was developed ~10 years ago when there was no Windows 10. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: For anyone wanting to follow, this is the closest i've found on crbug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=973776&q=%22Action%20Center%22%20os%3DWindows&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified